# How to load asp gridview control from client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have a method in a web service which is like this :

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public location[] getLocation()
 {
     string companyCode = Convert.ToString(Session["companyCode"]);
     //string userID = Convert.ToString(Session["userID"]);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     List<location> list = new List<location>();

     try
     {
         conn.Open();

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
         cmd.Connection = conn;
         cmd.CommandText = "getLocation";
         cmd.Parameters.Clear();
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyCode", companyCode);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", DBClass.cns_Active);
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         da.Fill(dt);
         conn.Close();
         foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
         {
             var loc = new location();
             loc.ID=Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
             loc.APIAddress = Convert.ToString(dr["APIAddress"]);
             loc.PostCode = Convert.ToString(dr["postCode"]);
             loc.ShostCode = Convert.ToString(dr["shortCode"]);
             loc.latLong=Convert.ToString(dr["latLong"]);
             list.Add(loc);
         }
     }
     catch
     {
         conn.Close();
     }
     return list.ToArray();
 }
```

where `location` is a class

and i am trying to load a grid using this method from client side, and here is the the code:

```
function getItems() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../WebService.asmx/getLocation",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
            $('#gvTrip').append("<tr class='gradeX'><td>" + data.d[i].ID + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].APIAddress + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].PostCode + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].ShostCode + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].latLong + "</td></tr>");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error in fetching record");
    }


});
}
```

here `gvTrip` is a asp gridview control

so the problem that i am facing is that the grid is not loading with data but data is coming from that method , i have checked using alert 
Please help

Comment: You have a list of Location, return this as an jSon object, and then loop through this object and build an HTML table instead of using a GridView. You are on the right track, but instead of trying to append to a GridView, append to a normal HTML <table> which you will give the id of gvTrip, and this should work.

Comment: yeah that i did but i want to load in gridview. is it imposable?

Comment: You can probably loop through your array and append it to the GridView, it renders a HTML table after all. However, I don't think you should expect this data as part of the postback, it is just in the DOM as part of the table, but not really part of the GridView's dataset.

Comment: so is it possible to do this.. i am still looking for this. can i really load gridview from client side using webservice and javascript

Comment: As I said, the GridView will still render as a HTML table, so you can append anything to it in the client side, but you should not expect to do anything with this data in the code behind, say from a asp.net button click for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The gvTrip inside ajax is a server side control. so try using:

```
$('<%=gvTrip.ClientID %>').append("Your string");
```

Comment: Would this really work? This would append HTML into a server side control.